# ImGui sample code/basic initialisation not working (Windows and Linux)

Tags: c++, imgui

I am trying to setup ImGui to make some apps in, however I can't get it working. I installed the `.h` and `.cpp` files from the GitHub, https://github.com/ocornut/imgui, and followed the instructions to allow the project to compile, which it does. But on Windows and Linux (i've tried both), it spits out a runtime error, (stopped responding Windows, segmentation fault (core dumped) Linux). This is the sample code that was published,

```
#include "imgui.h"

int main()
{


    // Create a window called "My First Tool", with a menu bar.
    ImGui::Begin("My First Tool", &my_tool_active, ImGuiWindowFlags_MenuBar);
    if (ImGui::BeginMenuBar())
    {
        if (ImGui::BeginMenu("File"))
        {
            if (ImGui::MenuItem("Open..", "Ctrl+O")) { /* Do stuff */ }
            if (ImGui::MenuItem("Save", "Ctrl+S"))   { /* Do stuff */ }
            if (ImGui::MenuItem("Close", "Ctrl+W"))  { my_tool_active = false; }
            ImGui::EndMenu();
        }
        ImGui::EndMenuBar();
    }

    // Edit a color (stored as ~4 floats)
    ImGui::ColorEdit4("Color", my_color);

    // Plot some values
    const float my_values[] = { 0.2f, 0.1f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 0.9f, 2.2f };
    ImGui::PlotLines("Frame Times", my_values, IM_ARRAYSIZE(my_values));

    // Display contents in a scrolling region
    ImGui::TextColored(ImVec4(1,1,0,1), "Important Stuff");
    ImGui::BeginChild("Scrolling");
    for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++)
        ImGui::Text("%04d: Some text", n);
    ImGui::EndChild();
    ImGui::End();



    return 0;
}
```

Now this code doesn't compile due to `my_tool_active` and `my_color`, so I added these 2 lines to the code before the `ImGui::Begin()`:

```
bool my_tool_active = true;
float my_color[4] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1};
```

So now when I compile and run, it gets to the `ImGui::Begin()` and then crashes at that stage. I have tried it in a much smaller example where it is just the `ImGui::Begin()` and `ImGui::End()` and placed print statements around it, and it showed that it never finished executing the `Begin()`.

Comment: My advice is to use a debugger and figure out why the code crashes.

Comment: Are there any certain ones that are good? I've never used one before and the code for the GUI itself I haven't written.

Comment: @GgsgnHdjwngnf Where did you get that sample code from? The [examples](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/docs/EXAMPLES.md) have some library initialization which seems to be missing from your code.

Comment: It seems to be the code from the README.md file.

Comment: On windows I recommend using Visual Studio Community 2019 as the IDE and debugger. And I mean Visual Studio Community and not Visual Studio Code which has a similar name but it is less beginner friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Imgui doesn't provide a graphics backend, neither it creates a window or a graphics API context. You have to provide it by yourself (using OpenGL/DirectX/Vulkan ecc...) or use a library that creates one for you (SDL/glfw ecc...).

Refer to the sample directory to a more complete sample.

This one is using sdl+openGl.
https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/example_sdl_opengl3/main.cpp

Comment: Ohhhh okay thats why I was getting confused then, thanks. If it doesn't provide that, then what does it actually do lol?

Comment: Graphics library like openGL just render triangles and lines. ImGui uses the graphics library to draw the user interface.